# What is the profession / preferred way to handle input validation

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new to C# and SQL. But over the last few years while learning both in college a question really begins to burn inside me. Here it is:

It seems to me that there are really two very generic ways to handle input validation (i.e. checking for required fields, and data in the correct ranges ect).

The first, and the way shown traditionally is: Once you develop your UI, and have connected it to a database back end in some manner. On the user interface, you check for correct input, such as blank text boxes, number ranges, or to ensure a radio or check box is selected ect.

The second, and the way shown in database development is: To set check constraints on fields such as no nulls allowed, unique values, and even ranges and required fields.

My dilema is this. Given that in modern languages like C# you can do general execption handling, and also given that major league fault tolerance is built into most databases like SQL Server with regard to handling data changes in respect to committing all or none. Details like this, and to this level, would be hard to program in anything but the simplest of programs.

So my question is, why not build all the requirements directly into the table at the database back end. Take advantage of the aformentioned fault tolerance, and just forget about programming if statements to ensure correct data is input, and instead just use a generic catch all execption handler if the data is not committed.

Perhaps that is how it is done, if so I would really like to know for sure. If not, why? My preference is to avoid writing code whenever possible. Less code, less debugging, and less problems when it comes to updating. So I would tend to go with that approach of letting the DB back end do the work. Is this the generally correct thing to do.

I know that general execption handling is considered "expensive" in terms of resources. But surley once you get past 5 or 10 if statements to handle different fields and their constraints, it must be more efficient code wise to just do a general execption handler. It certantly seems easier to understand overall. (At least the way I do it).

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: interesting, i've often wondered about this myself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put data management rules for complex data validation in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881821/where-to-put-data-management-rules-for-complex-data-validation-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: This cracked me up: "My preference is to avoid writing code whenever possible. Less code, less debugging, and less problems when it comes to updating."

Comment: @jack-t-colton - I do software development, the primary rule in our college is to always blame it on the DB guys! :->

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here is why you need it in both places.

First the integrity of the data should be paramount and data can be changed directly in database tables (deliberately through a script to say update a million prices or by accident or even by disgruntled or criminal employees trying to disrupt the database or steal from the company).  Therefore is it reckless to avoid using constraints directly in the database and it leads to bad data.

Now at the user interface level, you want to prevent the user from wasting his time submitting bad data and you want to prevent the servers and networks from wasting their time trying to process it, so you write checks at that level. Plus you don't want the data in an inconsistent state if you need to insert to several tables and aren't using a transction (which you should be using but I would suspect it happens less often than it should.) Plus the users hate it when you try the insert and it fails and tells you that X is wrong and then they fix X and now Y is wrong but it was wrong before, the process just didn't get as far as Y before.

Comment: +1 - the data itself is absolutely paramount, so put constraints and other rules as close to the data as possible (in addition to usability at the app tier). If you miss something in the app, it's better that the app fails than if the database gets corrupted.

Comment: +1 - I totally agree with the DB integrety. As pointed out, DB's have extream fault tolerance built in. So for example, a partial recordset cannot be input, its either an all or nothing affair. I also like your point regarding the network traffic. This would seem like a good reason to do checking on the UI, without them you have to submit the data and wait for the DB to tell you it is not correct. I must learn about using transactions. Thank you for highlighting this, can you recommend a good resource. Finally your point on X and Y both wrong. Good design makes sense. Thank you for your answer

Comment: For SQL server look at Transactions in Books Online for the SQL code to do transactions. Also look at try catch.

Comment: After some time and taught I have accepted this as the final answer because you hit on two important points that I do consider very important. First the fact that data integrety is paramount. Second only to this, is the user experience (good design). Typically DB people say let the UI handle the error checking, less network traffic, more secure, all that stuff. While programmers say let the DB handle it, more fault tolerance, transaction mgmt ect. You have hit on two very different, but much more important and practical considerations. I still prefer to let the DB do the work though! :->

Answer (score 5):

You do both.

Create constraints at the DB - level, and check for those constraints on the client level as well.

The validation on the DB makes sure that no invalid data gets in your DB, no matter how the data is inputted.
The validation at the client side improves the user-experience.

Comment: I agree with your arguement totally. With one execption. When handling a general execption you can handle specific cases first, and less and less specific cases, right back to a generic case. You can do this in one block of code and the user wont know any different. i.e. a number out of range. This will generate an error when the record is comitted to the DB which your program can then take in and handle as a specific execption. As opposed to actually writing code behind the UI or in some logic elsewhere and duplicating exactly what the DB will do for you for free. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sometimes you need a data access layer between the client and DB where you can implement validation of additional business rules, or complex constraints that the DB engine is unable to represent elegantly.

Comment: So are you saying then that the examples taugh in college are just that, examples for tutorial. In the real world we will let the DB handle errors when possible or elegant (such as the simple examples I gave), and only program when really needed for very special cases.

Answer (score 5):

You generally can't build all the logic for checking into the database. Also not validating user input sufficiently is a good way to open yourself up to attack.

One way to write lesss guard code in every method is 'Code Contracts' a product of microsoft research.

All input should be validated both client and server side. Always.

Also with a giant catch it would be hard to tell which field was in error. So you would end up writing a lot of which field exploded code at the other end.

Comment: +1 I must make effort to learn about "code contracts". I have never heard of them before. Can you recommend a good resource for beginners. Another great point is the security issues you mentioned. We have not covered that yet. Are code contracts designed to deal with security also. If so then I am still unconvinced however of the need write code for handling every possible type of user input as opposed to using an execption handler. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

While I generally advocate putting as much in the database as possible (which means that you can have a high degree of confidence about the "raw" data as possible), that isn't always possible, even with the powerful constraints and triggers available in SQL.

In addition, there are high-level "integrity" things which may change over time, and it is not realistic to always have temporally-dynamic conditions in constraints.  i.e. all HR records since 2007 must have a non-NULL birthdate, but prior ones are allowed to remain NULL, but any row cannot ever be set back to NULL.

My point is you can almost never put it all in the database.

Put the things in that you can, and put others at higher levels in the system.  The database is a very important part of any system, but it isn't the only part.  As long as its design helps it protect its perimeter and be able to provide reliable service and guarantee what it says it will guarantee so that other parts of the system can rely on their assumptions, then that's about the most you can ask for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all answers made here, like that UI control improves drammaticaly UX for the user, and can completely change "image" of your app, that validation on DB is made for correct insert the data to DB, but on client it have to be done for correct insert of the client data.

Consider an example of standalone enterprise app. A client work at home, he filled 20 invoices late night on his notebook in Mongolia. The day after he came back, and sync it with his office SAP server. If the error will be figure out only during sync of the data, you can imagine what  awful is this situation.

Just an example. There could a plenty of others, I'm sure.

Good luck.

Comment: Good example. But surley you would program you client side database on your notebook with the same constraints as those that exist on the server. Doing so will ensure your data can be committed the next day without failure while still not requiring all the extra code behind the UI. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Francis: by saying "compile" in my post I mean the hypothetical client fills invoice's form of some app that perform only DB input data validation, I'm not talking about programming a software :)

Answer (score 0):

Its 2 years later and I have a decent amount of experience now. I am not going to accept my answer as the right one as many here have done a great job and I am very happy with their answers. But I want to add another important consideration that looking back over my experience has not been highlighted here. I also use stack overflow for reference as I progress and I always find myself looking back over my questions and answers which is another reason I wanted to add this. Like a note to my future self.

While working at that company, I was asked to build an app that would do job abc. With this I also had to build part of the database. As I was finishing with the company I learned that they were writing another app which would use my database. Effectively my point is, that as many have pointed out, data is paramount, and you don't know how it is going to be accessed when you're gone.

I have also learned that there are 3 places that data needs to be verified:

1. on the actual database as explained
2. on the server side code behind which is not the same as the DB or client side validation
3. on the client side

There is another worry. With the advent of new tech like tablets and smart phones. This is yet another place where validation has to be implemented. The same rules for a 4th time (unless its a web app).

I later learned that prior to MVC we had CGI forms which had something to do with handling data over the network (I humbly admit ignorance on hardware side) but from what was explained to me it seems there may even be a 5th place to do validation (although I am open to being totally wrong about that).

I think the next guru in computer science will make a name for himself if he can find a way to abstract all that verification and validation to one place so that such rules don't have to be altered in a bunch of places.

worst case:

1. DB
2. Server side code
3. Client side code for web apps

What about if:

1. There may be a native client app (i.e. windows, linux or mac (at least 6 now))
2. There may be various phone apps (android, iPhone, and win phone to name 3, at least 9 now))
3. There may be some CGI or whatever

This totals 10+ places without much exaggeration and there are other operating systems.

Even for a simple age range this is getting to be messy, but what if they bring out some new email format, or other complicated validation, or you have to change a bunch of validation rules. Now you have to modify them across at least 3 or 4 places which in itself is bad.

The major problem with that is that you are modifying a lot of code and infrastructure that has been invested in, tested, and usually proven to work and delivered to the market...

As the number of client sides grow, modifying well tested code, can't be a good thing. I think this is going to be a major headache for the future. I wonder if there will be a design pattern or best practice to resolve it. If anyone knows of one, please tell me.